# Change the "add a comment to this post" tooltip on Area to something more informative

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, user-interface, tooltips

(This is really minor, but here goes...)

If you hover your mouse over the "add comment" link for this question, it says "ask author for clarification about this post". On Area51, you get this instead:

[image: area51 add comment tooltip]

Could this be improved by adding a brief description of WHY users should add comments? This *could* potentially cut down on the number of people answering proposal questions in the comments (like Mr. Robert Cartaino ♦ reminds us in the post above), although I doubt very many people read these tooltips since we all **think** we know how we should be using them.

**TL;DR:** This would be a great place to summarize what comments are acceptable rather than just telling the user that they can use the "add comment" link to post a comment

Comment: Downvoters care to comment? Do you like the old tooltip better?

Answer (score 9):

We implemented this, although not quite exactly how it was suggested above.  We opted for placeholder text in the comment text area that gives a suggestion, similar to @RobertHarvey's, that should give some guidance to users with regards to the kinds of content we're looking for in comments.

Answer (score 3):

If we do this, I recommend:

```
Add a comment to clarify this post, or to ask for clarification.
```